# Algorithm's complexity : Big O notation

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

`O( sqrt(n) ) = O(n)  ?`

We should find c and n0 verifying :
0 ( sqrt(n) ) < c*n ; c>0 and n>n0

How to find c and n0 ? or should i find another idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `n > 1`, we have `√n > 1`, hence we have the following inequality:

```
√n < √n * √n = n, for any n > 1.
```

So we can take c = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 2 to prove that √n = O(n).

#### Remark

Strictly speaking, you should avoid writing down something like `O(√n) = O(n)`. Big-O notation is for describing the asymptotic upper bound of a **function**, but `O(√n)` is not a function.

`O(√n) = O(n)` is an abuse of notation, it really means the following:

```
If f is a function such that f(n) = O(√n), then f(n) = O(n).
```

In our case, if for any function *f* we have `f(n) = O(√n)`, since `√n < n` for any `n > 1`, clearly we have `f(n) < c * √n < c * n` for any `n > 1`, and hence `f(n) = O(n)`.

Comment: You proved that sqrt(n)=O(n) , then how to prove O(sqrt(n))=O(n) ? Is there a rule like `f(n)=O(g(n)) => O(f(n))=O(g(n)) ` ?

Comment: But wait , you have proved just `f(n) = O(√n) => f(n)=O(n)` , Isn't necessary to prove `f(n) = O(n) => f(n)= O(√n)` so that  `O(√n)=O(n)` ? I still a little bit confused .

Comment: Well spot! The problem why this notation should be avoid is because `=` is a reflexive relation, `O(√n)=O(n)` implies `O(n)=O(√n)`, which is definitely not what we mean! (because it is completely wrong)

Comment: You usually see something like `O(√n)=O(n)` when you are deriving an asymptotic upper-bound of a function, where you see a chain of big-O equalities like `f(n) = O(g(n)) = O(h(n))`. But you **should not** write something like `O(√n) = O(n)` as a standalone statement.